# C# .exe to .dll / execute or run .dll as if it were a .exe

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Okay so for example I have 2 projects, Form1.exe & console1.exe, what I want is to execute console1.exe within form1.exe, so I used,

```
        if (isLogin(true))
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Welcome!");
            Process.Start("console1.exe");
```

Now the problem with this is, in order to execute console1.exe the user must store that file locally, now the issue with that is, he/she can execute console1.exe without executing form1.exe

So what I did was used ILMerge to merge the .exe's as you would a .dll but it's unable to now find console1.exe, so merging didn't work.

So now my conclusion was to reopen visual studio & create a reference .dll out of console1.exe.

Problem with this is executing the .dll as if it were still a .exe without calling methods separately, so to execute the file as if it were one method.

So basically executing the parent class, which will then follow up with the sub classes.

Now is there anyway I can reference console1.exe and merge it to form1.exe preventing users from running it as a solo application, or is it possible to set rules on console1.exe that it may not execute unless called from form1.exe, or the second conclusion to run it as a .dll reference library in one command not multiple sub classes.

Comment: You'll want to run the second application as a .dll. `Process.Start` is the same as launching it from Windows, so there's not a real way to restrict the calling application. Typically when converting a .exe to a .dll, you only need to worry about creating an entry point since you're not using same entry point that an .exe would use, and then calling that from your parent application. Posting as comment since it has been a **long** time since I've done this in C#/.NET.

Comment: Are you trying to restrict users from running the console1.exe because you dont want them to have access to console1.exe (to know about it) or are you just trying to make sure they can't run it manually so that it executes its contents? Basically, would it still be ok if someone ran console1.exe and it did nothing by running it manually? It just started and stopped?

Comment: Yeah pretty much anything to prevent it being ran without being used by form1.exe

Answer (score 0):

You have two options if you need to start it as a process. Both of which are not fool proof because they use a simple technique of obfuscation.

1. You change the file extension of the **console1.exe** to something like **console1.notAnExe**. You can still start this as an application using the `Process.Start()` method. You just need to create a `ProcessStartInfo` object and set the `UseShellExecute` property to `false`. Beware because this option means anyone with access to change the extension back to .exe can run the application.

   ```
   private static void StartAProcess(string proc)
   {
       var ps = new ProcessStartInfo(proc);

       ps.UseShellExecute = false;

       var p = Process.Start(ps);

       p.WaitForExit();
   }
   ```
2. You use a simple technique within your console1.exe start up method `Main(string[] args)` that reads in a special command line parameter. If this command line parameter exists, you continue processing. If the command line parameter does not exists, you just return. Beware because anyone that knows the command line parameter can still start your console1.exe and pass that command line parameter within a shortcut.

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       if (args == null ||
           args.Length <= 0 ||
           !args[0].Equals(
               "/SpecialParameter", 
               StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
       {
           return;
       }

       // Do something if the /SpecialParameter exists.....
   }

   private static void StartAProcess(string proc)
   {
       var ps = new ProcessStartInfo(proc);

       ps.UseShellExecute = false;
       ps.Arguments = "/SpecialParameter";

       var p = Process.Start(ps);

       p.WaitForExit();
   }
   ```